# Topic Modelling in Python, String in Python

Tags: python, topic-modeling

I have a created tags from comments and wants to test it on `comment_test` data. The tag `df` is as follows

```
Tag1                   Key words
Brand Reputation       brand OR brands OR reputation OR your company
.                      .
.                      .
```

(plz note that I am removing OR, " punctuation from Key words). My test data is as follows,

```
Comments
some rather long reputation
.
```

I need to create flag variables for each tag in comment_test data so that each comment will be marked in tags as 1 or 0. I want to know if there is a function in python which can check the comment and pick the key word and if it founds then mark 1 in respective flag variable else 0. I have tried below test code to check the comment for first tag however it shows only Nan as this `.loc` function require exact match. Appreciate your help on this.

Code : -

```
#Post importing data frame 

##remove punctaution from data

def remove_punc(value):
     return re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]',r'',value)

df['Key words']=df['Key words'].apply(remove_punc)

## converting into list 
list_1=df['Key words'][0]
list_2=df['Key words'][1]
list_3=df['Key words'][2]
list_4=df['Key words'][3]
list_5=df['Key words'][4]
list_6=df['Key words'][5]
list_7=df['Key words'][6]
list_8=df['Key words'][7]
list_9=df['Key words'][8]
list_10=df['Key words'][9]
list_11=df['Key words'][10]
list_12=df['Key words'][11]


#def txt_split (value):
     #return ([x for x in map(str.strip,txt.split('OR')) if x],value)

#df['Key words']=df['Key words'].apply(txt_split)
##txt=your_string
##txt.split('OR')


### extracting 'OR' from the list
a=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_1.split('OR')) if x]
b=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_2.split('OR')) if x]
c=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_3.split('OR')) if x]
d=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_4.split('OR')) if x]
e=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_5.split('OR')) if x]
f=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_6.split('OR')) if x]
g=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_7.split('OR')) if x]
h=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_8.split('OR')) if x]
i=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_9.split('OR')) if x]
j=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_10.split('OR')) if x]
k=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_11.split('OR')) if x]
l=[x for x in map(str.strip, list_12.split('OR')) if x]   

### Data
Comment_test  =   pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
### Tagging
Comment_test["Tags"] = np.nan
Comment_test.loc[Comment_test.comment.isin(a), "Tags"] = "Brand Reputation"
```

Comment: having variables named `a, b, ..., z` in Python is often a code-smell. You should keep your namespace clean by storing the values in collections instead.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, above code is just an example. My actual code is different.